# Increase TDP on 3060 Laptop GPU

Tags: drivers, nvidia, power-management, laptop

I have a Legion 5 Laptop with a 3060 GPU. I can switch the power profiles with an FN button. On the medium and high settings it uses 130W on Windows, on the silent one 80W.

On Ubuntu 20.04 with kernel 5.8.0 and NVIDIA driver 465.19.01 the GPU only uses up to 80W. No matter the power profile. This effectively limits the GPU's performance.

How can I increase the TDP? I already tried setting the TDP via the driver, but that didn't work:

```
ubuntu:~$ sudo nvidia-smi -i 0 -pl 130
Changing power management limit is not supported for GPU: 00000000:01:00.0.
```

Any other ideas?

Comment: Other people on the nvidia developer forums are experiencing the same issue: https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/has-anyone-been-able-to-run-an-rtx-3060-laptop-gpu-at-more-than-80w-on-linux/192959. No solutions yet as of posting this.